# OPC-UA open source framework

Tags: node.js, opc-ua

I'm writing a OPCUA client using this SDK:
[Node-OPCUA](http://node-opcua.github.io/)
Are there any other open frameworks built for OPC-UA?

Answer (score 2):

The [OPC Foundation](https://github.com/OPCFoundation) itself provides .NET (C#), C, and Java reference implementations on GitHub.  There is also a [Python](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua) implementation I have used a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Have you [tried](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=opc+ua) [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+opc+ua)?

I maintain the [Eclipse Milo](https://github.com/eclipse/milo) project, for example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need a high level-async-scalable ready platform... so I'm using nodejs. But I'll take a look at your project!